# Decimal Confusion in VBA

Tags: vba, decimal

I run different scripts using VBA on my German computer with an English Excel 2013 version installed on it. My local decimal settings are set to be international, e.g. 123123 is displayed as 123,123.00.

However, when I program with VBA, the decimal changes.

For example:

```
sub decimal_problem()

dim sDecSep as string
dim sThSep as string

sDecSep = Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)  ' sDecSep = "."
sThSep = Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator) ' sThSep = ","

Fmt= "#" & sThSep & "##0" & sDecSep & "00" 
'Fmt looks like "#,##0.00" which is what I want

Msgbox(Format(123123,Fmt)) 'Fmt="#,##0.00"

end sub
```

The number in the Msgbox is `123.123,00` which is the German number format and definitely not the format I specified before.
When I change the format in a Spreadsheet I get the correct separators (e.g. `"#,##0.00"` returns `123,123.00`).

Do you have a solution for that issue? 
As I need to calculate with the formatted number, I try to avoid to change the number to a string and use the replace function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check your "Regional Options". Moving to [SU]

Comment: Do you mean the regional options of my OS? Even when changed, the issue is still present.

Excel is set to use the international standard ("." as decimal separator), however, VBA doesnt accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The code you mentioned above is showing the output you wanted that is 123,123.00 and not 123.123,00.
Also as soon as you will assign this value to a range in a sheet this Text value will get converted to numeric automatically. for ex - thisworkbook.sheets(1).range("a1").value = Format(123123, Fmt)--This will assign cell a1 walue as 123,123.00 which will be in numeric

please let me know if I have not understood your scenario.

Comment: I am guessing you are using a non-German computer? My computer gets the different output.
But the advice with copying it to a sheet might work!

My ultimate goal is to have the user type in a number with a TextBox. I try to give this number the desired format with TextBox1_change().

Comment: I kinda worked around the problem. I stored the values in a public variable, with format() and replace() I then changed the "," and the ".".
This is not what I actually wanted to do, but it was the easiest way.

When I copy the number to a cell and then read it again to the TextBox, the format changes to the wrong format again.
Any other idea why VBA gets the wrong separators?